# TOSHIBA Qosmio X770 Recovery doesn't work anymore

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, diskpart

I bought some years ago a Toshiba Qosmio X770 PSBY5A-04T01W which comes with Windows 7 home premium. This laptop is the version which supports only 8 GB RAM, no 3D technology.

I've been using it as usual for the last 3 years but I wanted to do a factory reset but it doesn't work at all. I remember that I did a factory reset 3 years ago after 3 months later of buying this laptop. And in that time it worked well.

But now, here is the problem:

1. I shut down the laptop
2. I turn it on.
3. Immediatelly I hit F12 to list the boot options
4. HDD Recovery YES YES
5. The laptop restarts
6. I see the black screen with the message WINDOWS LOADING FILES.
7. Then I see the logo of Microsoft with the message STARTING WINDOWS
8. It displays the windows 7 wallpaper with the cursor of loading trying to load the recovery
9. HERE IS THE PROBLEM. It restarts and then tries to find the boot from network
10. I use a CD a windows 7 DVD which allows to fix the boot partition and then I can restart Windows 7 without problems. Inside the option from CD I only have the INSTALL NOW and Repair... but it doesn't find a system image

So, I can never reset the laptop from recovery options.

I have never manipulated the disk neither its factory partitions.

So if go to **Control Panel** > **System and Security** > **Administrative tools** > **Computer management** > **Disk management**. I would easily see my healthy recovery partition.

[image: Disk management]

I found this interesting article : [Windows 8 - Recovery partition not recognized after hard drive swapping](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Beacon-D-J-and-S-Series/Windows-8-Recovery-partition-not-recognized-after-hard-drive/ta-p/1317485) But as in the picture my type is not a GUID is just a number

[image]

Then I went to c:\windows\system32\Recovery\ where I found the file Reagent.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<WindowsRE version="1.0">
    <WinreBCD id="{020841ce-ccaf-11e1-984c-c00e6b91fbd9}"/>
    <WinreLocation path="\Recovery\WindowsRE" id="3760468764" offset="1048576" guid="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"/>
    <ImageLocation path="\Recovery\WindowsRE" id="3760468764" offset="1048576" guid="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"/>
    <OsInstallLocation path="" id="0" offset="0" guid="{020841be-ccaf-11e1-984c-c00e6b91fbd9}"/>
    <InstallState state="1"/>
    <OsInstallAvailable state="0"/>
    <WinREStaged state="0"/>
    <OperationParam path=""/>
    <OsBuildVersion path="7601.18933.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.150715-0600"/>
    <OemTool state="0"/>
    <BootKey state="0"/>
    <IsServer state="0"/>
    <ScheduledOperation state="4"/>
</WindowsRE>
```

Curiously I see that after some changes, the OsInstallLocation shows the well GUID because before it was {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

I tried to force replacing manually the empty GUIDs with the guid that I found with the bcdedit command but then when I apply the **reagentc /disabled** and **reagentc /enable**, this reset the reagent.xml file to the empty guid {0000...}

Then I found this article "[6758: Windows 7, "Repair your computer" F8 boot option not working (SOLVED)](https://forum.acronis.com/forum/6758?page=1)" from that amazing guy named "Mark Wharton" who solved all the users' problems one by one. I follow carefully the instructions and after that, I duplicated a **Windows Boot Loader** section with the path **ramdisk=[c:\Windows\System32.....]** which I realized that it doesn't change anything at all the problem. This below my report with the command **bcdedit /enum all**

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \bootmgr
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {020841ce-ccaf-11e1-984c-c00e6b91fbd9}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \windows
resumeobject            {d7224c79-880c-11e5-9dbe-806e6f6e6963}
nx                      OptIn

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {020841c6-ccaf-11e1-984c-c00e6b91fbd9}
device                  ramdisk=[C:]\Windows\System32\Recovery\020841c6-ccaf-11e
1-984c-c00e6b91fbd9\Winre.wim,{020841c6-ccaf-11e1-984c-c00e6b91fbd9}
path                    \windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Recovery Environment
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
osdevice                ramdisk=[C:]\Windows\System32\Recovery\020841c6-ccaf-11e
1-984c-c00e6b91fbd9\Winre.wim,{020841c6-ccaf-11e1-984c-c00e6b91fbd9}
systemroot              \windows
nx                      OptIn
winpe                   Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {020841ce-ccaf-11e1-984c-c00e6b91fbd9}
device                  ramdisk=[\Device\HarddiskVolume1]\Recovery\WindowsRE\Win
re.wim,{020841cf-ccaf-11e1-984c-c00e6b91fbd9}
path                    \windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Recovery Environment
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
osdevice                ramdisk=[\Device\HarddiskVolume1]\Recovery\WindowsRE\Win
re.wim,{020841cf-ccaf-11e1-984c-c00e6b91fbd9}
systemroot              \windows
nx                      OptIn
winpe                   Yes

Resume from Hibernate
---------------------
identifier              {d7224c79-880c-11e5-9dbe-806e6f6e6963}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \windows\system32\winresume.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {resumeloadersettings}
filedevice              partition=C:
filepath                \hiberfil.sys
debugoptionenabled      No

Windows Memory Tester
---------------------
identifier              {memdiag}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \boot\memtest.exe
description             Windows Memory Diagnostic
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
badmemoryaccess         Yes

EMS Settings
------------
identifier              {emssettings}
bootems                 Yes

Debugger Settings
-----------------
identifier              {dbgsettings}
debugtype               Serial
debugport               1
baudrate                115200

RAM Defects
-----------
identifier              {badmemory}

Global Settings
---------------
identifier              {globalsettings}
inherit                 {dbgsettings}
                        {emssettings}
                        {badmemory}

Boot Loader Settings
--------------------
identifier              {bootloadersettings}
inherit                 {globalsettings}
                        {hypervisorsettings}

Hypervisor Settings
-------------------
identifier              {hypervisorsettings}
hypervisordebugtype     Serial
hypervisordebugport     1
hypervisorbaudrate      115200

Resume Loader Settings
----------------------
identifier              {resumeloadersettings}
inherit                 {globalsettings}

Device options
--------------
identifier              {020841c7-ccaf-11e1-984c-c00e6b91fbd9}
description             Ramdisk Options
ramdisksdidevice        partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
ramdisksdipath          \Recovery\WindowsRE\boot.sdi

Device options
--------------
identifier              {020841cf-ccaf-11e1-984c-c00e6b91fbd9}
description             Ramdisk Options
ramdisksdidevice        partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
ramdisksdipath          \Recovery\WindowsRE\boot.sdi
```

Everything looks fine. Then I followed these steps in order to verify if the content of my recovery partition has not been deleted.

1. I opened a command line prompt as administrator
2. I executed the diskpart command
3. I selected the volume which contains the recovery partition
4. I executed the command **assign**
5. This "mount" a new drive F: which in fact it makes my partition visible
6. I did F: ENTER, then I found a Recovery folder but inside there's no files seen from Windows Explorer(even if I set the option to "Show the hidden files")
7. So I realized that the files and folders are hidden. I went to that drive F: and I executed the command **dir /a**. I found everything inside.

These are the folders and files that I found inside the Recovery folder

```
\Recovery
    \Logs
       \Reload.xml
    \System32
       \Recovery
           \Reagent.xml
    \WindowsRE
       \boot.sdi
       \winre.wim
```

The Logs folder is new after I executed the command **bootrec rebuildbcd** from the CD of Windows after of my failed attempts to recover my windows.

Finally, I tried to do the recovery from Windows.

1. I when to **Control Panel** > **System and Security** > **Backup and Restore**
2. Recover system settings or your computer
3. Advanced recovery methods
4. Use a system image you created earlier to recover your computer
5. Do you want to backup your files? SKIP
6. Restart your computer and continue the recovery. RESTART
7. I saw after a restart the Windows 7 Theme Wallpaper with message dialog with the brand of Toshiba .... I thought maybe this time is gonna work!!!!!
8. Error: F3-F100-0009

Please, I know this is tedious but if someone can help me with this I would really appreciate it. I'm running out of ideas!! I want a factory reset with all the drivers from toshiba using my recovery partition. Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT - UPDATE**

For someone who suffered like me with the Toshiba Qosmio X770 and the drivers. I used my DVD of Win7 and I installed it. I couldn't use the recovery partition anymore. So I did a clean install and then the nightmare of finding the right drivers. I screwed up my installation (boot) like 6 times because a driver conflict. I downloaded all of these drivers from **support.toshiba.com** which were filtered by laptop serial number and support for Win7 x64. However not all the driver are compatibles.

After finding one by one... I found a post where someone suggested to download the [Toshiba Application Installer for Win 7](http://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=2475695) where even my model was not listed. I risked to use it and it detects all your hardware and downloads and installs all the drivers MAGICALLY. So with this you don't require your recovery partition anymore.

1. DVD of Win7 (Can be used but not retail)
2. Your valid serial key number that comes with your laptop
3. Toshiba Application Installer for Win7

Comment: Depending on your internet speed, it probably much faster to just download the drivers from Toshiba support, backup your Windows license, reinstall a vanilla Windows 7, restore the license, and restore the drivers than attempting to fix your recovery partition

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo - Why is what appears to be the answer to your question contained within the actual question?

Comment: @Ramhound Because OP edited my comment into his question? I don't know, do I commit a precrime?

Comment: I pinged the wrong user.

Comment: I really appreciate the comment of @MartheenCahyaPaulo, but for the kind of question I was expecting a more technical answer about my specific situation. Even though the comment it's not an answer so I cannot mark it aswell. I included a further detail for all those Toshiba users that I found the Toshiba Application Installer link. As I said trying a clean installation with the supposed drivers from support.toshiba.com, screwed up my boot 6 times, I took me so much time trying to repair my Win7 installation.